# GET DIAGNOSTICS equivalent for mysql version older than 5.6

Tags: mysql

Is there anything equivalent to GET DIAGNOSTICS of mysql 5.6 version for lower versions of mysql?

I am using mysql 5.5 and I want do something like this

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 
    @p1 = MYSQL_ERRNO, @p2 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p3=MESSAGE_TEXT,@p4=TABLE_NAME;
    select concat('Failed - ',@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4);
END;
```

But 5.5 doesn't support this, is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL documentation for version 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/condition-handling.html), there doesn't seem to be an equivalent, but this article pointed me in the direction of using `SHOW WARNINGS` inside my handler, and using a local variable inside the handler to check if it was actually called (if that's needed).