# MYSQL 6 - You have an error in your SQL Syntax 'Diagnostics Condition 1'

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql-8.0

I have version 8 of MySQL but need to update a database stored procedure that is using 5. When I test this code in version 8 I do not receive any errors. However when I add it to the stored procedure on the the older version I receive the following error:

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near 'DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 errstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, msg =
> MESSAGE_TEXT;

This is the code that I have inserted that is causing the error.

```
DECLARE errstate CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE msg TEXT;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 
    errstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
    msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;

END;
```

I could not find any documentation specific to version 5 for using GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION.

Comment: Sorry The Impaler it is version 5, that was the Workbench version. I will edit.

Comment: I just found this article from Stack Overflow that answered my question. Apparently this is not a command available in version 5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611700/get-diagnostics-equivalent-for-mysql-version-older-than-5-6